# Area of a triangle, how to determine height?

Tags: trigonometry

Today I came across this problem:
[image: Example problem]

The task is to find the length of AC given area $A = 40$, angle $\alpha=115$ and $BC = 10$.

I feel like this should be relatively straightforward to solve, but for some reason I struggle to do so. I feel like what gives me difficulty is that the angle is obtuse, which makes it harder for me to find the height of this triangle after choosing base = BC.

If we know that $A=\frac{1}{2}b\cdot h$, we can choose $b = BC = 10$, and then find the height using $h = (AC)\cdot\sin\alpha$. Then after filling in we get $A= 40 = (10) \cdot (AC)\sin115$, which we can solve.

I have difficulty in the step where we find the height $h=(AC)\cdot\sin\alpha$, because the corner alpha is obtuse. If this corner wouldn't be obtuse, it seems much more intuitive for me.

Can someone make this more clear for me?

Comment: Area of a triangle is given by the formula $\frac {1}{2} (ab)(sinC) $ where a and b are sides opposite to vertexes A and B.

Comment: Yes I know this, but the derivation of b in this case is what gives me trouble.

Comment: Since $40=\frac12\times10\times b\times\sin\left(115^\circ\right)$, $b=\frac8{\sin\left(115^\circ\right)}$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks for your answer. I do understand that, but I don't understand why $h = b\times\sin(115)$ for the height of the triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the triangle $ABC$ as shown in the figure

[image]

Since $\angle ACB = 115^\circ$ we infer $\angle ACD=65^\circ$
Notice that height h is $AC(\sin65^\circ)$
Also we know $$\sin\alpha=\sin(\pi-\alpha)$$
so we infer $h=AC\sin65^\circ=AC\sin115^\circ$

I hope your doubt is cleared.

Comment: Thank you this makes it more clear, extending the BC line is what I was looking for.